# Biber locale does not match system language nor biblatex language

Tags: biber

Suppose I have a file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,language=british]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}

@article{HauserYangBerwickTattersallRyanWatumullChomskyLewontin2014,
  Author = {Hauser, Marc D. and Yang, Charles and Berwick, Robert C. and Tattersall, Ian and Ryan, Michael and Watumull, Jeffrey and Chomsky, Noam and Lewontin, Richard},
  Date-Added = {2014-04-27 10:34:40 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2014-07-06 19:19:20 +0000},
  Doi = {10.3389/fpsyg.2014.00401},
  Journaltitle = {Frontiers in Psychology},
  Number = {401},
  Title = {The Mystery of Language Evolution},
  Volume = {5},
  Year = {2014},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pharetra
odio a lacus tristique, eleifend consectetur sapien pellentesque.
Integer dictum mattis dapibus. Vivamus in sagittis nisi. Nunc quis
adipiscing mauris, ac malesuada sapien. Sed rhoncus sapien sit amet dui
imperdiet, sed sollicitudin turpis condimentum. Ut sed rutrum leo. Nam
hendrerit blandit convallis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas quis
bibendum ipsum, et fermentum metus. Nam semper congue malesuada.

\cite{HauserYangBerwickTattersallRyanWatumullChomskyLewontin2014}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I can compile it fine. If I do `$ biber <filename>.bcf` I get the following:

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.9
INFO - Logfile is 'paper.blg'
INFO - Reading 'paper.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'bibliography.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibliography.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'paper.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
INFO - Output to paper.bbl
```

This suggests to me that biber has a locale and it's en-US. But my system language, as reported by `$ echo $lang` is en_GB.UTF-8. The language option for biblatex specifies British English. I've noticed that in the .bcf the 'sortlocale' key is just English, which I take it means *US* English. So, I presume, that's why biber reports that locale.

Question: does it matter for my plan to make documents that follow British English conventions that biber has this locale setting? If so, how can I change it? Or is there no difference between UK and US English sorting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just load babel with option `british` and `csquotes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{HauserYangBerwickTattersallRyanWatumullChomskyLewontin2014,
Author = {Hauser, Marc D. and Yang, Charles and Berwick, Robert C. and Tattersall, Ian and Ryan, Michael and Watumull, Jeffrey and Chomsky, Noam and Lewontin, Richard},
Date-Added = {2014-04-27 10:34:40 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-07-06 19:19:20 +0000},
Doi = {10.3389/fpsyg.2014.00401},
Journaltitle = {Frontiers in Psychology},
Number = {401},
Title = {The Mystery of Language Evolution},
Volume = {5},
Year = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pharetra
odio a lacus tristique, eleifend consectetur sapien pellentesque.
Integer dictum mattis dapibus. Vivamus in sagittis nisi. Nunc quis
adipiscing mauris, ac malesuada sapien. Sed rhoncus sapien sit amet dui
imperdiet, sed sollicitudin turpis condimentum. Ut sed rutrum leo. Nam
hendrerit blandit convallis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas quis
bibendum ipsum, et fermentum metus. Nam semper congue malesuada.

\cite{HauserYangBerwickTattersallRyanWatumullChomskyLewontin2014}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the .blg file:

```
[0] Config.pm:320> INFO - This is Biber 1.9
[0] Config.pm:323> INFO - Logfile is 'britishbib.blg'
[52] biber-MSWIN:274> INFO - === %a %b %e, %Y, %H:%M:%S
[52] Biber.pm:333> INFO - Reading 'britishbib.bcf'
[160] Biber.pm:635> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[207] Biber.pm:3051> INFO - Processing section 0
[251] Biber.pm:3189> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'bibliography.bib' for section 0
[256] bibtex.pm:990> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[257] bibtex.pm:864> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibliography.bib'
[298] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-GB' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[298] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-GB' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[298] Biber.pm:2928> INFO - Sorting list 'nty' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'en-GB'
[298] Biber.pm:2932> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-GB'
[302] bbl.pm:517> INFO - Writing 'britishbib.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[303] bbl.pm:606> INFO - Output to britishbib.bbl
```

**Added**:
For use with `polyglossia` and `Xe/LuaLaTeX`, replacelines 2-5 of the previous code with:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}%
\usepackage[backend=biber, sortlocale=en-GB]{biblatex}%
```

Comment: If not using US English, it is recommended to load `csquotes`: British and American quotation conventions are not the same.

Comment: You're right, but that was not the main problem. Thanks for pointing it.I've modified my code.

Comment: I don't think I need `filecontents.sty`. The built in environment that does what I want.

Comment: I've been using `polyglossia`, rather than `babel`, because I use `XeLaTeX`, which doesn't set en-GB. But I could probably switch.

Comment: OK. I didn't know well the `filecontents` package, just used it because I was told to. I'll change my answer.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with polyglossia variants and biblatex. I reported on GitHub, hope it will be fixed.

Comment: @Bernard You mean that British English is considered a variant of (US) English, and the locale isn't sensitive to the variant?

Comment: That's what it seems to be.

Comment: @Tom: I've updated my answer for use with `polyglossia`. The problem is solved with adding relevant options to `biblatex` and `csquotes`.